# Python script terminates itself after calling a subprocess withing an IF statement

Tags: python

I am working on a GUi based study manager, and when a user clicks on a button, the script opens a chrome window containing a mathemathics exercises repo. The script runs fine, but upon clicking on the button, it terminates itself. The GUI is being created via PySimpleGUI.

This is the layout portion of the code, containing the button:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Your typed chars appear here:')],
          [sg.Text('It. Lit. pages', size=(15, 1)), sg.Input(key='str_ITLP')],
          [sg.Text('MAT quiz pages', size=(15, 1)), sg.Input(key='str_MATQ')],
          [sg.Text('Math exercises', size=(15, 1)), sg.Input(key='str_MATH')],
          [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit'), sg.Button('Maths exercise repo')]]
window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout)
```

---

This is the subprocess code:

```
if event == 'Maths exercises repo':
        sp = subprocess.Popen([CHROME, 'url'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What I would need to happen is that the script keeps running (i.e. the GUI doesn't just nuke itself upon opening chrome) so that I may continue using the ohter functions of the script.

P. S.
Yes, both *subprocess* and the chrome path are imported within the script, given that chrome **actually** runs.

P. P. S.
I am an **absolute** python beginner and this is literally my first script, so please show mercy towards my code.

Comment: You need to wrap that part of your code in a `while True:` block. Take a look at Example 2 in PySimpleGUI's [description](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/)

Comment: `Popen` call is fine. The problem is in the rest of the code you did *not* provide.

Comment: How about an error message?  Why not use webbrowser instead of launching chrome?  import webbrowser. Humility goes a long way as a beginner so maybe not pointing at a package & saying it's nuking itself.